# Flutter Firebase Authentication not moving to Dashboard page after authentication

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to authenticate user login with firebase, but I have a problem when it has to move to a dashboard page after successful login. The login is successful, but it's not doing anything after login.

Here's my code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const FirsApp());
}

class FirsApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirsApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
            create: (context) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance)),
        StreamProvider(
            create: (_) =>
                context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanged,
            initialData: const [])
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'First App',      
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: appPrimaryColour,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: appBackGroupCoulour,
        ),
        home: const AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User?>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return const Dashboard();
    }
    return const SignInPage();
  }
}

class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: emailController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Email",
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: passwordController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Password",
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: emailController.text.trim(),
                    password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                  );
            },
            child: Text("Sign in"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Stream<User?> get authStateChanged => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  Future<String?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return "Singed in";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
}
```

I did put a breakpoint on the AuthenticationService and it did return Singed in, but it never moved to the dashboard page. The dashboard page is just an empty page with a container and a text field.

Comment: You probably want to use a `StreamBuilder` listening to the authentication changes. It will pick up on changes and then initiate navigation.

Comment: Where should I use the StreamBuilder?